# Spring Boot service rejecting PUT requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors

We just recently upgraded our Spring Boot project form 2.7.11 to 3.1.2 and somewhere in the process lost the ability to receive PUT requests. Since the upgrade we have been receiving the following error when attempting PUT requests: `o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor : Reject: HTTP 'PUT' is not allowed`. We only get this with PUT, all other methods are successful. In reviewing the changes made during the upgrade I could not find anything that would have casued this, I also could not locate anything in our code that was different for PUT requests compared to others.

We have a `CorsConfigurationSource` in our `WebSecurityConfiguration` class that looks like this:

```java
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(false);
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source; 
    }
```

I have also tried to modify it as such with no luck:

```java
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

I tried to add the following class as well but that didn't make any difference:

```java
@Configuration
public class CrossOriginConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

On our Controller we have the `@CrossOrigin` annotation. I have tried to modify it with an origins value like this `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` but still had our PUT rejected.

Any help at all would be appreciated. At this point I have no idea where to even look for this problem, Google doesn't even have any exact matches for the phrase `Reject: HTTP 'PUT' is not allowed` and all of the possible solutions I have found are not working.

Edit:
It works when sending the request from Postman but not from the UI (localhost:9500). All of my other requests (POST, GET, etc.) are working from the UI, just not PUT.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in our `filterChain` method of the WebSecurityConfig. What we had in place was this:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request ->  new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()))
            .authorizeRequests(request -> request...
```

The `new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()` was causing the problems. When I replaced it with what we had in the `CorsConfigurationSource` like this it started working for PUT again:

```java
http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request ->  {
                        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                        configuration.setAllowCredentials(false);
                        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
                        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
                        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
                        return configuration;
                    }))
            .authorizeRequests(request -> request...
```